# How to convert number to length?

Tags: lengths, random-numbers

I'm trying to generate a ["word cloud"](http://www.wordle.net/) by using `\mbox`es with random spaces around words.

In the code below I've removed stuff that change the font size, and I've replaced `\mbox`es by `\framebox`es for debug purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[first=1, last=10]{lcg}

\newcommand*{\wordtag}[1]{%
    \framebox{\vspace{3pt}\hspace{5pt}#1\vspace{1pt}\hspace{6pt}}%
}


\begin{document}
\rand


\wordtag{color}
\wordtag{animals}


\end{document}
```

When I replace length with `\rand` (i.e. `\vspace{\rand pt}`), I get the following error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

And why the `\rand` at the beginning of the document doesn't print anything?

Is there a better way to produce a word cloud?

Answer (score 5):

The manual of the `lcg` package states:

> `\rand`
>       Each call of the command `\rand` will write a new random number to the counter
>       provided by the user with the key [=package option] `counter` or to the standard counter of this package `rand`. Now it's possible to do whatever can be done with counters.

So `\rand` is not expanding to a number and therefore doesn't typeset anything and can't be used in a length. You need to use it first and then can use the `rand` counter using `\value{rand}`, e.g. `\vspace{\value{rand} pt}`.

You could also use the math engine of the `pgf` package. It provides `\pgfmathrandom{x,y}` (also accessible using `\pgfmathparse{random(x,y)}` and friends) and stores the result into `\pgfmathresult`. Here `x` and `y` are the same numbers as `first` and `last` with `lcg`.

```
\usepackage{pgf}
% ...
\pgfmathrandom{1,10}
\vspace{\pgfmathresult pt}

% or even
\newlength{\randomlength}
\pgfmathsetlength{\randomlength}{random(1,10)}
\vspace{\randomlength}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lcg) for `lcg`, it says

> Each call of the command `\rand` will write a new random number to the counter provided by the user with the key ⟨counter⟩ or to the standard counter of this package—`rand`.

To get the value stored in the counter `rand` use `\therand`. So,

```
\vspace{\therand pt}
```

will work.

Comment: Right, `\therand` works as long it has its original meaning of `\arabic{rand}` which uses `\number` internally. I personally prefer `\value{rand}`, which is more efficient (not that it counts much). However, `\therand` might be saver for normal LaTeX users because `\value{rand}` exposes the counter register directly and would cause an error if used in-text on its own.